# xamarin not open Main.axml

Tags: c#, xamarin

After a project android creation (empty app), I try to open the file Main.axml, but the result is:

> System.ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null.
>       Nome parametro: o
>          in System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetIUnknownForObjectNative(Object
>   o, Boolean onlyInContext)
>          in Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows.WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.UpdateD3DImageFromSharedSurface()
>   in
>   E:\A_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows\WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.cs:riga
>   140
>          in Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows.WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.RenderDesignerItemVisual(DesignerItem
>   item) in
>   E:\A_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows\WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.cs:riga
>   131
>          in Xamarin.Designer.Windows.WpfSurfaceRenderer.QueueRender(DesignerItem
>   item) in
>   E:\A_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer.Windows\WpfSurfaceRenderer.cs:riga
>   361

How can I figure out?

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: NO, I solved with the reinstalltion of visual studio